# Passing a proc as a block to a method

Tags: ruby, proc

When I try to pass an arbitrary block to `each_with_object` method, it raises an error:

```
%w(foo bar baz).each_with_object([]) &->(i,m) { m << i.upcase }
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `&' for #<Enumerator: ["foo", "bar", "baz"]:each_with_object([])>
```

When I try to pass a block to `inject` method, it also raise an error:

```
%w(foo bar baz).inject('') &->(m,i) { m + i.upcase }
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `' for "foo":String
```

But it works if I don't pass an initial value:

```
%w(foo bar baz).split.inject &->(m,i) { m + i.upcase }
```

And it also works when I pass a block to `each` method.

```
%w(foo bar baz).each &->(i) { puts i.upcase }
# FOO
# BAR
# BAZ
```

Can anyone explain this behaviour? How can I pass arbitrary blocks to the first two examples?

Comment: What does this have to do with the Code::Blocks C++ IDE?

Comment: @JörgWMittag Sorry, I added that tag by mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `&` argument prefix turns an argument into the method's block (by calling `to_proc` on it). Since it's an argument, it must go inside the parens if you are using them, i.e.

```
%w(foo bar baz).each_with_object([], &->(i,m) { m << i.upcase })
```

At the moment, ruby is interpreting the `&` as the binary operator, and trying to do:

```
(%w(foo bar baz).each_with_object([])  & (->(i,m) { m << i.upcase }))
```

Hence the error. I'm not sure why you're not just doing:

```
%w(foo bar baz).each_with_object([]) { |m,i| m << i.upcase }
```

Comment: It was just an example, my block structure keeps more difficult logic. Thanks

Comment: “turns an argument into the method's block”: Just wording, but to be more precise, it calls `to_proc` method on the argument and passes it to the called method as a block.